# Todo List implemented in React not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I m trying to Implement a todo list in React. It's just a basic app that lets you add elements to the ordered list. The screen doesn't show anything and react application kind of breaks down when I write something in the input box

```
  super()
        this.state={
            todos : []
        }

   elex(event){
        if (event.key==="Enter"){
            const Lex=<List key= {event.target.value} text={event.target.value} />
            this.setState((previous) =>{
                const Lex1=[...previous]
                Lex1.push(Lex)
                return {todos:Lex1}
            })
        }

     <div>
        const change=this.state.todos
        <h1>Hello There</h1>
          <form>
              <input 
               type="text" 
               placeholder="What to remind" value={this.state.val}
               onKeyPress={this.elex}/>
            </form>
            <ul>   
                <h2>{change}</h2>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I have stored my state as an Array containing the List Components. Calling the event handler I m trying to push a list component inside an array and display the array in the render function. However, when I write something and press return, my screen goes blank

Comment: Refactor your code it's unreadable

Comment: Did Some Refactor. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Add a new handler and todo state variable

```
handleChange = (e) => {
this.setState({todo:e.target.value})
}
```

On enter event, push the todo to todos array

```
//on enter event

this.setState({todos:[...this.state.todos,this.state.todo]})
```

Change the input tag as below:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="What to remind" value={this.state.todo} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

Comment: Thnx I would try. Basically the gist is that make a seperate state variable for newly formed list and push that. Thank You. Also what's the problem in my code, sorry I m new in React